# SimpleDateFormat gives java.lang.classcastexception: java.util.date

Tags: java, date, casting, simpledateformat

```
String str = "13/06/2011";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that your `Date` class is actually a `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: If I remove the cast, it gives me compilation error.
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Comment: @vijay you should import `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Thanks Howard. I did that and now I am not getting the cast exception. But now I am getting the below exception. Java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 12/21/2011

Comment: @vijay Do you now have another format (other than posted in your question)? It looks like because with above format it should work (nevertheless you seem to have MM/dd/yyyy now instead of dd/MM/yyyy).

Comment: This is my exact code .....SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM:dd:yyyy");
        
Date convertedDate;
try {
         convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dob);
dateFormat.parseObject(dob);
        
        } catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
and DOB is in this format : 12/21/2011

Comment: @vijay: `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")` is what you need.

Comment: @vijay your date format specifies colons (:) as separators while you use slashes (/).

Comment: Yeah thanks John and Howard ... it worked fine. I thought : is standard..anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What does your import statement say? Are you importing some other class (for example `java.sql.Date`) by accident? What does the compiler say when you remove the class cast (which should not be there)?

Comment: If I remove the cast, it gives me compilation error.
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Comment: And there is your answer. Wrong import statement.

Answer (score 2):

`DateFormat.parse()` returns an instance of `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`.
In order to convert from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`, I do the following:

```
java.util.Date fromDate = df.parse(fromdate1);  
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(fromDate.getTime());
```

Comment: After about an hour of looking, I found this and it works great.