# Convert String to date and compare

Tags: java

One of the fields which I extract from a database is a date in string format and I need to convert it into a date type to compare with another date.

How do I do this please?  Everything I have tried so far gives me an error of `java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date` and this is attempting the following example;

[simpledateformat-gives-java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327392/simpledateformat-gives-java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-date.)

An example of the date extracted in string format is "2012-10-15 09:00:29.157".  I think the format to declare is *yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS* but not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code, and the stack trace of the exception. You shouldn't read dates as strings. You should read them as dates or Timestamps.

Comment: Well, what `Date` type did you `import`? If you imported `java.sql.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` parser returns `java.util.Date`, then it's not strange that you get a class cast exception

Comment: You may be using 'java.sql.Date'. 
'DateFormat.parse()' returns an instance of 'java.util.Date' and not 'java.sql.Date'. 
If you want to use 'java.sql.Date' convert the date from 'java.util.Date' to 'java.sql.Date', Do the following:

java.util.Date fromDate = df.parse(fromdate1);  
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(fromDate.getTime());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means you are assigning  `java.util.Date` in `java.sql.Date`

From your example you have to do following :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(""2012-10-15 09:00:29.157"");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `java.util.Date` from `java.sql.Date` as follows:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(resultSet.getDate("Column").getTime());
```

Alternatively you can convert the `java.sql.Date` to either `java.util.Calendar` or Joda library's DateTime and perform comparisons.

If you are looking at parsing date, then `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` is your friend.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
java.util.Date date = format.parse("2012-10-15 09:00:29.157");
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `Date` as Vikdor showed. then get the `long timestamp = date.getTimestamp();`

Now this long value is millisecons since 1970 utc. just compare by this value.